# Describing/creating VRT/CSVT files of variable length space separator for gdal_rasterize command

Tags: gdal, vrt, gdal-rasterize

I have LAS points (DTM) files with space separators. And the problem is for Z coordinate:

```
 360020.678  6245020.453   0.008
...
 364895.678  6245245.453  14.970
...
 364370.678  6246870.453 112.312
```

String looks like: `[space]X[space x2]Y[space xn]Z`
Format for Z could be `[space][space][space]Real(5.3), [space][space]Real(6.3) or [space]Real(7.3)`.
I tried with *.csvt file, but it didn't work out.

```
"Real(11.3)","Real(13.3)","Real(8.3)"
```

ogrinfo output:

```
field_1: Real (11.3)
field_2: Real (13.3)
field_3: Real (8.3)
field_4: String (0.0)
field_5: String (0.0)
field_6: String (0.0)
field_7: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(T_test):1
  field_2 (Real) = 360020.678
  field_4 (String) = 6245020.453
  field_5 (String) = 
  field_6 (String) = 
  field_7 (String) = 0.008
  POINT Z (360020.678 6245020.453 0)
...
OGRFeature(T_test):2095
  field_2 (Real) = 362370.678
  field_4 (String) = 6245270.453
  field_5 (String) = 
  field_6 (String) = 15.712
  POINT Z (362370.678 6245270.453 0)
...
OGRFeature(T_test):17110
  field_2 (Real) = 362745.678
  field_4 (String) = 6247145.453
  field_5 (String) = 128.325
  POINT Z (362745.678 6247145.453 128.325)
```

GDAL version: `GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14`
OS Win10.

Is it possible to rasterize such points with the standard [bin](http://www.gisinternals.com/) version?

Answer (score 1):

After long attempts, a solution was found:
*.csvt file content:

```
"CoordX","CoordY","Real","Real","Real","Real","Real"
```

*.vrt file content:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="DTM_Points">
    <OGRVRTLayer name="T_test">
      <SrcDataSource>CSV:T_test.txt</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT field_2, field_4, field_7 FROM T_test WHERE field_7 NOT NULL</SrcSQL>      
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint25D</GeometryType>
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_2" y="field_4" z="field_7"/>    
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="T_test">
      <SrcDataSource>CSV:T_test.txt</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT field_2, field_4, field_6 FROM T_test WHERE field_6 NOT NULL</SrcSQL>
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint25D</GeometryType>
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_2" y="field_4" z="field_6"/>    
    </OGRVRTLayer>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="T_test">
      <SrcDataSource>CSV:T_test.txt</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT field_2, field_4, field_5 FROM T_test WHERE field_5 NOT NULL</SrcSQL>
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint25D</GeometryType>
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_2" y="field_4" z="field_5"/>    
    </OGRVRTLayer>    
  </OGRVRTUnionLayer>    
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

ogrinfo output:

```
field_2: Real (0.0)
field_4: Real (0.0)
field_7: Real (0.0)
field_6: Real (0.0)
field_5: Real (0.0)
OGRFeature(DTM_Points):0
  field_2 (Real) = 360020.678
  field_4 (Real) = 6245020.453
  field_7 (Real) = 0.008
  POINT Z (360020.678 6245020.453 0.008)
...
OGRFeature(DTM_Points):1891
  field_2 (Real) = 362295.678
  field_4 (Real) = 6245245.453
  field_6 (Real) = 14.19
  POINT Z (362295.678 6245245.453 14.19)
...
OGRFeature(DTM_Points):20074
  field_2 (Real) = 361870.678
  field_4 (Real) = 6247520.453
  field_5 (Real) = 150.562
  POINT Z (361870.678 6247520.453 150.562)
```

It may not be the optimal solution, but in this case it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the open option MERGE_SEPARATOR=YES https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html.
I saved the three lines from your question with a header line `x y z` and tested:

```
ogrinfo mergetest.csv -al -oo merge_separator=yes
INFO: Open of `mergetest.csv'
      using driver `CSV' successful.

Layer name: mergetest
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 3
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
x: String (0.0)
y: String (0.0)
z: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(mergetest):1
  x (String) = 360020.678
  y (String) = 6245020.453
  z (String) = 0.008

OGRFeature(mergetest):2
  x (String) = 364895.678
  y (String) = 6245245.453
  z (String) = 14.970

OGRFeature(mergetest):3
  x (String) = 364370.678
  y (String) = 6246870.453
  z (String) = 112.312
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't help as the first character is also a space separator. As I wrote before - [space]X[space x2]Y[space xn]Z.

Comment: Then I suggest to fix the CSV file. I would use sed from msys or find some other alternative for Windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127318/is-there-any-sed-like-utility-for-cmd-exe.

Answer (score 0):

Faster solution with just 1 layer definition:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTUnionLayer name="DTM_Points">
    <OGRVRTLayer name="T_test">
      <SrcDataSource>CSV:T_test.txt</SrcDataSource>
      <SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT field_2, field_4, IFNULL(field_7, IFNULL(field_6, field_5)) AS Z FROM T_test</SrcSQL>      
      <GeometryType>wkbPoint25D</GeometryType>
      <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="field_2" y="field_4" z="Z"/>    
    </OGRVRTLayer>
  </OGRVRTUnionLayer>    
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

It's a pity it is not possible to specify the `merge_separator=yes` option inside the VRT file.